# I want to start the Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, linux

I run this:

```
$ postgres -D foobar
```

It just hangs.  There is no error message.  I newly created this database with the initdb command.  What should I do?

Comment: It doesn't "hang". [From the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html) "*By default postgres starts in the foreground*" - so your command starts it in the foreground and thus your console is "blocked". It's better to use `pg_ctl` to start it in the background or use the wrapper script provided by your Linux distribution (e.g. `service postgresql start`)

Comment: Which distribution of Linux are you using? You may find it preferable to install from a distribution-specific repository.

Answer (score 3):

From the INSTALL document

```
                                Short Version

./configure
make
su
make install
adduser postgres
mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
su - postgres
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test
```

So,

`initdb` initialises the system after the binaries have been put in place, either through an rpm or a source compile.

`postgres` launches the server (which is what you're trying to do)

`createdb` xyz creates a database of name xyz

`psql` is the command-line client

You could try

```
./bin/pg_ctl -D ./data/ -l logfile start
```

On running `initdb`, you should have received a message

===========================

Success. You can now start the database server using:

```
./bin/postgres -D ./data/
```

or

```
./bin/pg_ctl -D ./data/ -l logfile start
```

===========================

What I can suggest to you is to run the pg_ctl option - it's the one that I use, for what it's worth.

You appear to have confused the server command with a database access command. You should run `psql foobar` to access the foobar database, provided the server is already running - see above how to do that.